# Zend setRawHeader

Tags: zend-framework, http-headers

I have IndexController. I need to set raw header in indexAction.
I try to make

```
function indexAction(){
    $this->getResponse()->setRawHeader('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
}
```

But I see in Google chrome status 200 OK.

How set raw header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a 404, use:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404)
                    ->setRawHeader('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); // optional
```

If you don't explicitly set an HTTP response code, ZF will automatically send a 200 response if it was not overridden by `setHttpResponseCode`.  Once it sends all the headers it checks to see if a response code was sent, and if not, sends a 200 regardless of your rawHeader.

Comment: I modify your code and it works. $this->getResponse()-> setHttpResponseCode(405)-> setRawHeader('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed')->sendHeaders(); if do not call sendHeaders() headers don't set. Thanks for help.